# apt-get update : How to resolve 403 forbidden?

Tags: apt

I had initially by mistake deleted /etc/apt/sources.list, Then I've tried restoring default repositories as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories), but while exiting from there, I got the error:

`Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/xenial-getdeb/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 143.95.32.90 80], E:The repository 'http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb InRelease' is not signed.`

Also when I'm trying to run `sudo apt-get update`, but it is giving me following error:

`http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb InRelease 403  Forbidden [IP: 143.95.32.90 80]`

Comment: I dont understand why it is getting downvoted ?

Comment: What is it there for?   getdeb.net is not an official source for Ubuntu, nor on the list of mirrors that I can see  (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors).

Comment: Any possible way I can remove it from sources, I'm not able to identify which package is using that. Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I would remove (*or more likely comment it out; I prefer leaving a short date & comment on why I make any change*) using `vim`; ie. `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list` (or file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/..), but via 'gui' you can search for 'sourc' (start of 'sources') to view a gui-tool that will allow you to do it using mouse/gui, in the "Other Software" tab I'd expect to find it, you can remove the 'tick' & it'll be commented out via your gui [without comment/date on why].  *ps:  `vim` is an editor, and `vi` wasn't really user-friendly in the 1970s; so replace with whatever editor you prefer*

Comment: Backup your /etc/apt/sources.list and use https://repogen.simplylinux.ch to generate source.list freshly